# Terminal error (esLint) related to hasOwnProperty when compiling

Tags: commerce-cloud, eslint

Even the code working good…  i am getting this error on terminal.

```
if (response.product.hasOwnProperty('availabilityForPickup') {
   //Do something...
}
```

> Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object

```
ERROR in ./cartridge/client/default/js/product/detail.js

/cartridge/client/default/js/product/detail.js
161:38  error  Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object  no-prototype-builtins

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Can anyone give me any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is Lint error (just a notifier for any missing ";" or extra spaces or other stuff..). It won't break code in most cases. But helps to keep code clean.

I used this successfully:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(response.product, 'availabilityForPickup')) {
    //Do something...
}
```